# Weird results with Transform.TransformDirection()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using `portal.TransformDirection()` to simulate how the object the code is attached to would rotate if it were a child of the portal object without actually being its child.

This is the code and it works kind of but not really. Only if I rotate the portal Object around the Y axis. It still does something when I rotate around the other axes but not what I'm expecting.

I didn't find anyone else who had this problem so I thought I might ask.

I have a short video that demonstrates how it rotates (https://youtu.be/dfvr4IrA2SU) and here is the code on the object that should rotate with the portal object:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PortalArrow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform portal;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 eulerRotation;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = portal.position;
        transform.eulerAngles = portal.TransformDirection(eulerRotation);
    }
}
```

The variable `eulerRotation` is just a constant Vector3. nothing special about it.

Comment: I found out that Transform.TransformDIrection returns a Vector in a direction and not the eulerAngles of the Vector. I changed the line ```transform.eulerAngles = portal.TransformDirection(eulerRotation);``` to ```transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(portal.TransformDirection(eulerRotation));```, but the same problem still arises

Answer (score 0):

`eulerAngles` are **no direction** and it makes no sense to treat them like one.

The fact that it is also stored as a `Vector3` is a pure convinience.

---

> would rotate if it were a child of the portal object without actually being its child.

It sounds like you rather simply want

```
transform.rotation = portal.rotation;
```

Comment: I figured it out by now. Yes, the problem was that I treated eulerAngles as a vector. I didn't know at that time, the TransformDirection used direction vectors. transform.rotation = portal.rotation; doesn't work, because it disregards the current rotation. the solution was to switch eulerRotation with transform.forward, because that is a vector.